# how do i get data from array depending on some conditions

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have tables `T1` and `T2`. In `T1` I have column `cat_id` having integer values in array seperated by commma, e.g.

```
row1=1; row2=1,41; row3=40,1
```

In `T2` I have column id having single integer values, e.g.

```
row1=1; row2=40; row3=41; row4=0
```

Now depending on id selected from `T2` I want data from `T1`.

My problem is how do I apply the condition in `T1`. I am using CodeIgniter. I have tried like this.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('status', 'yes');               
$this->db->where('cat', '1');
$this->db->like('category_id', '1');
$this->db->or_like('category_id', ',1'); 
$this->db->or_like('category_id', '1,');
$this->db->get('T1')->result_array();
```

but the problem persists as for `id = 1`, if there is data in `T1` as 51,5 it also get selected.
How do i solve this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using FIND_IN_SET

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 on FIND_IN_SET(T2.id, T1.cat_id)
WHERE T1.status = 'yes' AND T2.cat = 1
```

If you think the extra records are coming you can use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN.
IN COdeigniter

```
$sql_query  =   "
            SELECT 
                * 
            FROM T1
            LEFT JOIN T2 on FIND_IN_SET(T2.id, T1.cat_id)
            WHERE T1.status = 'yes' AND T2.cat = 1  
            ";

$this->db->query($sql_query);
```

Comment: you are welcome but the good practice is to use seperate rows instad of comma seperated column

Answer (score 0):

As to the above question,using in_array() also helps.

```
$this->db->select('cat_id');
$row = $this->db->get('T1')->result_array();

$list = array();
foreach($row as $ind=>$val){
  $c_id = explode(',', $row['cat_id);
  if(in_array('1', $c_id){
    array_push($list, $val)
  }
}
```